# Node net.createConnection ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am trying to create a Socket server, but I keep getting `ECONNREFUSED` when I try and launch the server.

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createConnection(3000,'localhost',function(socket) {
     console.log('connected!');
});

server.on('error', function(e) {
     console.log(e);
});
```

Nothing fancy.

However when I try to run it `node server.js`, I only get an error message. Is there a step I am missing here? Is it maybe a configuration issue?

I am running node 0.10.32 if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: I came looking for the same issue. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

That error is your client cant connect to server. You can add this code to snip error.

```
server.on('error', function(err){
console.log(err.message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did your server start ? You can use `http.createServer` to create server listen on port 3000 and you connect to it.